# Printing bitmap on serial bluetooth printer in Android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, serial-port

I want to develop Print Service plugin for custom thermal printer which connects via bluetooth. Device does not support pdf format, so is it possible to request Print Job in bitmap format?

Comment: Did I answer your question? I'm actually pretty sure there is currently no way to request the print job to come in any format other than pdf

Comment: Yes, I think so. I think I will convert this pdf to bitmap using PdfRenderer as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to request the job to come in a different format. Your app can instead convert it to a bitmap. You can use the [PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) class to render pages of the pdf to bitmaps.